# Criar Grupos e Agrupar Itens Dentro Deles

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma tabela com itens e preciso criar grupos e denominar cada item ao seu devido grupo. Eu já os distribui por categorias, que no caso chamo de 'famílias', porém eu preciso agora agrupar elas respectivamente em grupos que sejam gerados automáticos que eu possa denominar um valor máximo.

[image: Essa é a tabela:]

[image: Código]

esse é o código que me retorna a tabela acima, porém eu precisava que retornasse separado desta forma aqui:

[image: Assim:]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Gabriel. Você já fez alguma tentativa de código para realizar a tarefa que deseja? Sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Quais grupos? Tem exemplos de como seria a resposta? faltou mesmo terminar a pergunta, sem contexto para finalizar.

Comment: Sim, na realidade eu quero distribuir itens que tenho no estoque que estão separados por categorias e distribuir nesses grupos que se chamam pallets,  ex: pallet1, pallet2 etc em automático.

Comment: Ok, mas, como seria essa separação?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode jogar o resultado numa collecion, em seguida utilizar a função groupBy().

```
$collection = collect([
    ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
    ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
    ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
]);

$grouped = $collection->groupBy('account_id');

$grouped->toArray();

/*
    [
        'account-x10' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
        ],
        'account-x11' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
        ],
    ]
*/
```

Dessa forma você terá uma lista dentro de uma lista. E na view tera duas Tabelas (subtable). Como você não postou sua view, e nem o resultado da consulta não tem como eu mostrar o exemplo pegando seus dados.